# Laravel 5.5: Parse error with character encoding

Tags: php, laravel, operators

I've returned to a Laravel project after a while and decided to create a new user via Voyager, but got the following error:

> Parse error: parse error in
>   /PathToProject/ApplicationName/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 233

When I checked, the line is:

```
return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);
```

I then did a project-wide search and found a lot of instances of `??`.

When I then checked the local repo via Git, there are no such changes to the code to reflect these changes.

I'm *guessing* this is a character encoding issue?

Anyone know what's happened, and how I could avoid this again in the future?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: _"how I could avoid this again in the future"_ - Upgrade PHP to an active  supported version. http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @B.Desai I'm using PHP 7.1.2, which is the reason I don't understand what's going on; it's the exact same version I'm using for two other Laravel projects without error.

Answer (score 3):

`??` is **Null coalescing operator** introduce in PHP 7. So if you are using lower version then it will throw an error.

`??` returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

So your expression:

```
$arguments[1] ?? null
```

is equivalent to:

```
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
```

// This is equivalent to:

```
isset($arguments[1]) ? $arguments[1] : null;
```

So if you are using lower version change your return statement to

```
return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], isset($arguments[1]) ? $arguments[1] : null);
```

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.1.2, which is the reason I don't understand what's going on; it's the exact same version I'm using for two other Laravel projects without error.

Comment: will you try once after replacing my suggestion?

Comment: If you're recommending I change the code to Laravel itself (there are hundreds of such instances across 44 files), then no. I'll have to find some alternative.

Comment: did you check the code $arguments[1] ?? null  works in other places of your program